# How can I "zero" the camera's rotation?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

Basically, I want to set the camera so that zero on the ***X** axis is straight ahead* instead of straight down.
I do not want to default blenders settings but the camera's settings; Like how you would zero a cube.

Comment: I don't think you can. Camera object looks straight down in its default condition, and you can't change that default condition, if I'm not misunderstanding what you're asking.

Comment: Might be nice if you were saying the reason you wanted to do this?  There should be a solution for any problem involved with it (like changing the axis on a constraint or driver; or, possibly, parenting the camera to an empty to create an inverse.)

Answer (score 4):

You can set delta transform rotation:

[image]

This way you can transform the object, but leave the usual transform values unchanged.